# Display:flex not resizing height in chromium and mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wanted my two row footer to resize according to screen size, works flawlessly with firefox but for some reason chromium and mobile devices only resizes the width of each image (height remains the max-height value).

CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-row{
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer-image{
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-row">
        <img src="./img/footer/ipl.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/ciic.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/carme.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/ips.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/coimbra.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/batalha1.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/batalha.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-row">
        <img src="./img/footer/fct.png" style="max-height: 50px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/compete.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/portugal.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/ue.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
        <img src="./img/footer/ue_fundo.png" style="max-height: 55px" class="footer-image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How should the images be resized? I think as long as you don't kinda specify a width/height on the img, the browser will do what they want. Maybe the following helps: `.footer-image { object-fit: contain; }` or `.footer-image { object-fit: cover; }`

Comment: object-fit: contain; did the trick, thank you so much